# "where exists" and Index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The query below doesn't seem to use indices that are set on col1 and col2. Can't I expect a SQL including "where exists" use indices?

```
select a, b
from   [dbo].[test] testA
where exists 
    (
    select *
    from   [dbo].[test] as testB
    where  
    testA.col1 = testB.col1
    testA.col2 > testB.col2
    )
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen looks like testA and testB are the same table...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, both "testA" and "testB" are the aliases for "test". The query above is much simplified, but basically the same as the real one.

Comment: Could you please share the temporary data what exactly you have in test table and what you need as a result.

Comment: Thanks Rajat. The original query is very complicated, with several datetime columns for ">"  and several int / varchar columns for  "=".

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
select a.a, a.b
from [dbo].[test] a
where exists (select 1
              from [dbo].[test] a2
              where  a.col1 = a2.col1 and
                     a.col2 > b.col2
             );
```

The best index is on `test(col1, col2)`.

I would be inclined to write this using `row_number()`:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2) as seqnum
      from dbo.test a
     ) a
where seqnum > 1;
```

This version assumes that `col2` is unique.  You might want `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I'll try both. I didn't even think of using rank/row_number.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add multiple columns index

```
create index index_test_all on test ("col1","col2","a","b");
```

## Query SQL:

```
select a, b
from   [dbo].[test] testA 
where exists (
  select 1
  from   [dbo].[test] as testB
  where  testA.col1 = testB.col1
    and testA.col2 > testB.col2
)   
;
```

---

## Execution Plan :

[image]

---

[DEMO SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e2ccc/1/0)

Comment: Thanks! I think "Index Scan" means that the query doesn't use the index, unlike "Index Seek". Please correct me if I'm wrong.